# Вместо значения выводится имя класса

Tags: c#, ооп

Нужно создать класс рациональных чисел (с числителем и знаменателем) и создать оператор сложения. Я это сделал, но видимо допустил где-то ошибку, потому что в консоль выводится не результат сложения, а имя класса (lesson5.RatNumb). В чём я не прав?

```
namespace lesson5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RatNumb numb1 = new(1, 2);
            RatNumb numb2 = new(1, 2);
            RatNumb numb3 = numb1 + numb2;

            Console.WriteLine(numb3);
        }
    }
}

namespace lesson5
{
    public class RatNumb
    {

        private int numerator { get; set; }
        private int denominator { get; set; }

        public RatNumb(int Numerator, int Denominator)
        {
            this.numerator = Numerator;
            this.denominator = Denominator;
        }

        public static RatNumb operator +(RatNumb numb1, RatNumb numb2)
        {

                return new RatNumb(numb1.numerator + numb2.numerator, numb1.denominator + numb2.denominator);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А как WriteLine определит, как именно вы хотите, чтобы он вывел класс в консоль? Даже я не могу определить, какой результат вы хотите получить. Покажите пример ожидаемого вывода в консоль.

Comment: @aepot Ну, результат типа "2/4". Как я понял, нужно для этого класса ToString переопределить

Comment: Да, нужно......

Comment: Скорее всего нужно прописать метод **override**

Comment: Ну, это стандартное поведение при печати класса во многих языках - печатать просто его неймспейс и название. Переопределите `ToString`, чтобы печатать то, что вы хотите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RatNumb` это ваш класс, вы можете написать гетеры для своих полей (потому что они `private`) и обращаться к ним.

Или можно переопределить метод `ToString()`, где вы уже опишите свою реализацию, например

```
public string ToString () {
    return $"Нумератор {numerator } Деминатор: {denominator } "
}
```